# How to apply filter on filterered data in elastic search using API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How could I be able to add multiple filters on the `index`
I want to  filter results by first_name and then by category using `elastic search client`

In `kibana` dashboard

[image: Kibana Image Filtering data]

I want to achieve the same functionality using the `elastic search client` and `python`
but I am able to filter the data only once

**Sample code**

```
@app.route('/get-data')
@login_required
def get_permission():
    uri = f'https://localhost:9200/'
    client = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=(session['username'], session['password']), ca_certs=session['cert'], verify_certs=False)

    body = {
        "from" : 0,
        "size" : 20,
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [],
                "filter" : [],
                "must_not":[],
                "should" :[],
            }
        }
    }

    index_data = client.search(index=index, body=body)
    return render_template('showdata.html', index_data=index_data)
```

I have looked into the [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/search-multi-search.html) but it's not working

**msearch method on devtool**
[image: msearch on elasticsearch]

`Result are not correct`

Is there any way to filter  or reapply the `search` method on filtered data without messing up the `old query`

Answer (score 0):

filter is an array in Elasticsearch DSL, and you should be able to provide multiple filters in that array, I can't help with python code, but in JSON filter array looks like

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "question_body_markdown": "i"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "customer.first_name": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want something else, let's say the above query `filtered` out the data, now I want to add another filter on the `filtered` data how could I write the `query`?

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh you can add multiple filters as mentioned in my query, Elasticsearch internally applies all the filters and return you filtered data, Hope this helps

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh  were u able to solve it

Comment: I could not, I hope you understand  my question, your way of filtering multiple fields will provide filtered data in `one go` but I did achieve this earlier, I don't want my data to be filtered in `one go` for example `user` filter data by `first_name` and got the filtered result and on top of that result user again filter the data by `last_name`, it's totally different scenario, check out the `msearch` image and zoom it in my question, you will get an idea